How to create a Gradio interface for PDF-based question answering in a Google Colab notebook?
I am trying to create a Gradio interface in a Google Colab notebook where I can upload a PDF file and ask questions related to its content. The interface should be able to answer the questions if they are related to the PDF.
Here are the requirements for my task:

Upload a PDF file.
Extract text from the uploaded PDF.
Use a pre-trained question-answering model to answer questions based on the extracted text.
If the question is unrelated to the PDF content, return "Sorry, the answer is not available."

I have tried the following code, but I am not sure if I am doing it correctly. Could someone please guide me on how to properly set this up in a Google Colab notebook?
Could someone please help me identify if there's anything wrong with this approach or suggest improvements? Thanks in advance!
